# AVAudioRecorder - Metering to voice detect

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, fft, voice

I need to develop an App witch plays an mp3 when a Voice is detected. Can I use the Speak here example? or does someone know an example of something like that?

I was looking at FFT and aurioTouch example but seems very difficult for me...

thanks in advance